# Laravel Auth::check() only returns true on post page

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I am new at Laravel and having some struggles with simple login and authorization pages.
I followed an awesome video tutorial by laracasts.com (credits for that one, really helpful).

**My situation:**
When implementing authorization to my page, the page after the login succeeds the authorization check.
So: loginform > press button > You are now logged in.

**My problem:**
After I press the back button and refresh, it still gives the login form. It shouldn't.

**routes.php**

```php
<?php

Route::get('login', 'SessionsController@create');

Route::get('logout', 'SessionsController@destroy');

Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');

Route::resource('sessions', 'SessionsController');

Route::get('admin', function(){
    return 'Admin page';
})->before('auth');



Route::get('dashboard', ['before' => 'auth', function(){

    return 'Dashboard';
}]);
```

**SessionsController.php:**

```php
<?php

class SessionsController extends BaseController{


    public function create()
    {

        if ( Auth::check() )
        {
            Redirect::to('/admin');
        }


        return View::make('sessions.create');
    }


    public function store()
    {
        if( Auth::attempt(Input::only('email', 'password')) )
        {
            // if(Auth::check())
            // {
            //  return 'check worked!';
            // }
            return 'Welcome ' . Auth::user()->username; //You are now logged in
        }

        return 'Failed';
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
        Auth::logout();

        return Redirect::to('sessions.create');
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public $timestamps = true;


    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public static $rules = [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'

    ];

    public $errors;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }


    public function isValid()
    {

        $validation = Validator::make($this->attributes, static::$rules );

        if($validation->passes() )
            return true;

        $this->errors = $validation->messages();
        return false;


    }

}
```

**create.blade.php**

```php
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')


    <h1>Create new user</h1>


    {{Form::open([ 'route' => 'users.store' ]) }}

        <div>
            {{Form::label('username', 'Username: ')}}
            {{Form::text('username')}}
            {{$errors->first('username')}}

        </div>

        <div>
            {{Form::label('password', 'Password: ')}}
            {{Form::password('password')}}
            {{$errors->first('password')}}

        </div>

        <div>
            {{Form::submit('Create User')}}
        </div>

    {{Form::close() }}
@stop
```

So to speak: It never goes to the 'admin' route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your authentication code is correct and working. What you have is something going wrong in any other part of your Laravel application, web server or even PHP.

Since we are not seeing all your code, we can just guess, so my first one would be the Session not being stored correctly. Currently logged users are stored in Laravel Session. So, check your session driver, if it's in 'native', change it to 'database', but you'll have to create a sessions table, look at the docs. If you are already using 'database', change it back to 'native' or even 'file'.

Comment: thanx for quick reply and confirming that the code should be correct. I tried couple of session drivers now but none of these seem to work how I expect them to. I tried 'native', 'database' and cookie. 
I don't have much code further than this.
I use the php.ini from wamp, can this be a problem?

Comment: My webserver didn't support session cookies for the folder Laravel was installed in.

Comment: what server did you use? I am seemingly the same problem

Answer (score -1):

Instead of run

```
 return 'Welcome ' . Auth::user()->username; //You are now logged in
```

Please try

```
 return Redirect::to('admin');
```

Comment: Unlikely to work since the OP tries to go to admin route manually and it just send the browser to auth again.

Comment: The code looks perfectly fine to me, that is why I ask to try it. I want to put it in comment, but it will ruin the code format. I need to check whether it is because Auth::check() has problem or something else.